# IE 9 Freeze on rendering

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

i have problem with website : http://re-cassiopeia.cz.vms6119.globenet.cz/ 
it works everywhere (chrome, IE 8,11, firefox, iphone, windows phone ),
but IE 9 all the time freeze on all pages.
I try this website on about 3 - 4 computers with IE 9 and it's same.
Developer console is clear.

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, that was because of respond.js, so i check browser and dont include respond in IE.

var a = /(msie) ([\w.]+)/;

```
        if (!a.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ) {
                $.getScript(respond_script,function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                    console.log( "respond.js :"+ textStatus ); // Success
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log("IE detected, oh god");
        }
```

Hope someone help.